# Version conflict detected for NuGet packages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am working on an ASP.Net core 2.1 web app project. I have 1 project in my solution and 3 other libraries, it's and advanced architecture (data access layer (`DAL`), business layer (`BL`), common layer (`CL`)), so i need to add references to connect some libraries and project. I have added `CL` reference to my project and to libraries `DAL` and `BL`. Now I have to add reference `BL` to my project, but when I add I get this type of error:

> Version conflict detected fr Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/ Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.1 directly to project 'WEB' to resolve this issue

When I am trying to install that version it says

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'WEB'

I can also mention that when I add reference `BL` to my project, it also includes `DAL`, and `CL` itself, (and `DAL` contains `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` (2.2.1), can't understand what's the problem, any ideas?

Additional Images of the problem in [here](https://imgur.com/a/rtjfP1i).

project.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\CL\CL.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

i have added `CL` reference as you can see, now i want to add `BL` reference and get this error

Comment: Toy should also show us the csproj files. There's nowhere near enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rtjfP1i    

check this out, from bottom to top

Comment: Its very clear from the error message that you've to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 2.2.1` to web before installing the other project

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan post the actual errors, not images of the errors. The `Package Manager` output window should explain *which* packages caused the conflict. Post the `PackageReference` elements from your `csproj` file, not images of the packages. The new `csproj` file format is so clean that you should be able to find them easily

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan in any case, the message explains how you can solve the problem - you reference different EF versions in your projects or their dependencies. One way to fix this is to add the NuGet package you want on your root project. If the problem is caused by mixed versions in your own project, the `Consolidate` tab in the Solution's package management page will show which projects use which versions

Comment: @AmanB read it carefully

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos EF only is installed in **DAL**, and the version i'm trying to install in my project is the same version, but it doesn't let me install as u you can see

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan I can't see anything in this question. Only a invalid link. This morning something was visible but not the *actual* output from the package manager, nor the `PackageReference` elements from the project file. Just a screenshot. Again, open the Package Manager at the **solution** level and check the `Consolidate` tab. In any case, you can't argue with the error message. Somehow, somewhere a *different* version is referenced. You can use the `Consolidate` view to fix the mixed versions or add the package you want to the root project

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan I think you missed **.Abstractions** in my comment

Comment: @AmanB I get the same issue when installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions sir

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sry, i misunderstand it, now i can see, there is No Packages found in Consolidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're having local directory path to one of your {projectName}.csproj file
Kindly review your .csproj files by Right clicking project and select Edit {projectName}.scproj

e.g

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore\2.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

If yes than go to Nuget Package Manager and add your library bu selecting nuget.org as Package Source

after restoring from nuget Package manager csproject file will have following tag Added
to

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="2.1.1" />
```

Here {projectName} is the name of C# project.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3cuMG8o,  this is my Project.csproj , it only contains 

 **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App**

when i'm trying to install 

 **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.1**

it should automatically add PackageReference to Project.csproj, but installation fails everytime

Comment: @Artur_Kamalyan those links return a 404. Why don't you just post the code in the question? It takes *less* time than uploading an image only to lose it and have to upload it again

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i can't upload images as i dont have +15 reputation, that's why i used to show them in that way, can you check the question now sir

Comment: Can you please clarify this part: "If yes than go to Nuget Package Manager and add your library bu selecting nuget.org as Package Source

after restoring from nuget Package manager csproject file will have following tag Added to". Im going to Manage nuget packages for the project which contains the HintPath but it already has nuget.org as Package Source? And how do i "restore from nuget package manager"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to chip in that i had the same issue but with EntityFrameworkCore 3.0 preview. I solved it by simply downgrading all entityframework 3.0(preview) nuget packages to latest stable (2.2).

Hopefully this helps someone aswell, took me hours...

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 check visual studio error window and identify which package is making the conflict .
make sure both packages have save version code