# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore not installing and hanging in Web API .NET Core app - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` not installing and hanging when I am trying to install `2.2.6` into my main project and a new C# .NET core project:

```
Restoring packages for C:\Repos\SnowdonAPI_02\SnowdonAPI_02\SnowdonAPI_02\SnowdonAPI_02.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.options/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.interactive.async/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions/index.json 253ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.options/index.json 146ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions/2.2.6/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions.2.2.6.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.options/2.2.0/microsoft.extensions.options.2.2.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/index.json 321ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.interactive.async/index.json 343ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions/2.2.6/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions.2.2.6.nupkg 203ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.options/2.2.0/microsoft.extensions.options.2.2.0.nupkg 189ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/2.2.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder.2.2.0.nupkg
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.interactive.async/3.2.0/system.interactive.async.3.2.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder/2.2.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder.2.2.0.nupkg 19ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.interactive.async/3.2.0/system.interactive.async.3.2.0.nupkg 30ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration/index.json 110ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration/2.2.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.2.2.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration/2.2.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.2.2.0.nupkg 13ms
Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.2.0.
Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.2.0.
Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.2.0.
Installing System.Interactive.Async 3.2.0.
Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 2.2.6.
```

It gets as far as here and doesn't go any further.  I then have to force quit visual studio.

Comment: Hi friend, it seems you've located the cause of the issue and found the workaround. You can consider adding your own answer below and mark it to indicate this issue is solved. Also members with similar issue can find useful info more easily. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your logs, maybe something interrupts the installation during the process.

Normally the possible cause of the issue can be: something broken in VS Itself, or one effect of extension, wrong action when installing the packages or nuget configurations.

I can't get the workaround which surely resolve your issue for the lack of detailed info, but there's some tips you can try:

1.Extensions=>Manage Extensions=>Disable them and restart VS to take effect

2.Update VS2019 to latest version, if it's the latest one, run a [vs repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

3.Make sure your project targets .net core 2.2 and install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` separately. It seems the nuget try to install the five packages at one time but as I know the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` doesn't depend on the other packages, so I'm not sure what the way you mean `when I am trying to install 2.2.6 into my main project`, more details is needed so that we can understand why installing the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore causes installing the other four packages.

For this, please create a new asp.net core web-api project, and install the 2.2.6-version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package by UI, check if the issue persists. If it persists, [clear the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) and delete the bin and obj folders, then restore packages for the new project by UI.

After you clean the cache, go `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`(This folder is used to store packages for those projects with packageReference format), now this folder is empty. Check if the nuget is really installing when you restore packages in VS. (If it really starts installing the package, the folder won't be empty after that)

4.For the packages it tried to install like `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.2.0`: It's strange behavior I think. Check the properties window for this package and I found its path is `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder\2.2.0`, so it's part of .net sdk I think. When we reference this package, it will fetch the package from that path instead of installing online. Not sure if this can be the cause of your issue,you can try repair the .net core 2.2 sdk and check if the package exists in that folder.

5.Make sure the installation is not interrupted for Internet issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll make a note of all your steps just in case something like this happens again.  However, my issue, if it helps others reading this, was my Visual Studio 2019 not using .NET Core SDK 2.2!  I was using 2.1 and it didn't like it for some reason.  This helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323167/version-conflict-detected-for-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-install, and here is the download: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks

Comment: @user1574598 Yes, I think I've mentioned it in Tip3, `Make sure your project targets .net core 2.2 `. The packages you're trying to install are for .net core 2.2. It seems that your issue is resolved after you donwload the 2.2 sdk, I suggest you can add the details as an answer to share the useful info.(Some situation without .net core2.2 will cause the nuget hanging?), add it as answer and mark to indicate it's solved. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was a result of having multiple projects in one solution where they didn’t all target the same version of NET.   I was able to get it working again by unloading the NET framework projects while I worked on the NET Core/NET Standard projects and vice versa.