# Error NU1605 when trying to run ASP.NET Core web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

I've created an ASP.NET Core API and defined my controller as follows:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SignUpController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DNNContext _context;

    public SignUpController(DNNContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        var merchantSignUpResponse = PutResponse();
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutResultAsync(int id, [FromBody]ProPaySignUp signUp)
    {
        try
        {
            await _context.SignUpResponses.AddAsync(PutResponse());
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return Accepted();
    }


    public SignupResponse PutResponse()
    {
        string url = "https://xmltest.propay.com/api/propayapi/";
        var credentials = GetCredentials();
        var request = BuildMerchantData();
        var restRequest = CreateRestRequest("/Signup", Method.PUT);
        restRequest.AddJsonBody(request);
        return Execute<SignupResponse>(restRequest, url);
    }
    private static RestRequest CreateRestRequest(string resource, Method method)
    {
        var credentials = GetCredentials();

        var restRequest = new RestRequest
        {
            Resource = resource,
            Method = method,
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,
        };
        restRequest.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
        restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", credentials);
        return restRequest;
    }

     private static T Execute<T>(IRestRequest request, string baseUrl) where T : class, new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Error: Exception: {0}, Headers: {1}, Content: {2}, Status Code: {3}",
                response.ErrorException,
                response.Headers,
                response.Content,
                response.StatusCode);
        }

        return response.Data;
    }
```

The solution builds successfully.  I then Launch Postman and enter the URL `https://localhost:44381/api/SignUp` with method PUT.  I receive a message stating `There was an error connecting to https://localhost:44381/api/SignUp.`

I then opened a command prompt at the directory in which my project resides and executed `dotnet run SOBProPayService`.  The error returned is

```
error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design from 2.2.0 to 2.1.2. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Is your API actually running? Have you checked you have the correct port? The `There was an error connecting to...` message is what you get when there is nothing to connect to.

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered that attempting to connect to an endpoint *that isn't running* won't work.

Comment: Here is the solution to your problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54289936/1526972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually get this error when I have inconsistent versions of packages. Check your .csproj file for Nuget package versions, or check package manager for updated packages and update if you have some available.